# Print contents of text box to a label in new form

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I am making a coin grading program, and I want when I press a button, the button will print the contents of the text boxes to a new form that I already created called form2, in the form of a label. So basically, I want to print the contents of the textbox into another form called form 2. When they are printed into the form I want them to be printed to a new line each time new data is entered.

I have looked into the StreamReader and Steamwriter classes, but I just can't seem to get this to work.

Any code samples would be GREATLY appreciated.

Thanks a million,

Max

Comment: Can't you just pass the in-memory value?

Comment: Not clear what the Stream classes have to do this.  Just pass the information to Form2 via a constructor parameter or a property when you initialize it.

Comment: Hi, i'm very new to this programming language/program and I don't know how to do the in-memory value or constructor parameter. Could you explain? @LarsTech

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is through the constructor for Form2:

```
Public Class Form2
  Public Sub New(textValue As String)
    InitializeComponent()
    TextBox1.Text = textValue
  End Sub
End Class
```

Then from Form1, you initialize it by passing the information:

```
Using f As New Form2(TextBox1.Text)
  f.ShowDialog(Me)
End Using
```

Comment: Thanks, but when I paste the code, every time i type in the text box, form 2 opens. I only want form2 to open with the data when you press button1. Also, I want the text to stay in form 2, even when the application is re-opened. @LarsTech

Comment: @user3448601 Much different question.  You need to store the information in a file or a database or in system settings.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you expose `Form2`'s textbox value as a property:

```
Public Class Form2
    ' (...)
    Public Property TextValue As String
        Get
            Return TextBox1.Text
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            TextBox1.Text = value
        End Set
    End Property
    ' (...)
End Class
```

Then, from `Form1`:

```
Using f As New Form2()
    f.TextValue = TextBox1.Text
    f.ShowDialog()
End Using
```

While the constructor approach suggested by LarsTech works, it will only allow you to set the value once. The property, on the other hand, will be editable (and reeditable) at any moment. Plus, it may make more sense to expose a simple property rather than binding a constructor to your text value depending on your design. You could even use both approaches at the same time.